# MYSQL Select records from table where there is no instance from a certain date

Tags: mysql

Utilizing MYSQL I am looking to query the records of certain individuals that have not voted during a specific election.

The table is formatted as such

```
Voter_ID | VOTER_NAME | ELECTION_DATE
---------|------------|--------------
10000001 | John Doe   | 1/1/2000
10000001 | John Doe   | 1/1/2001
10000001 | John Doe   | 1/1/2002
10000002 | Jane Doe   | 1/1/2000
10000002 | Jane Doe   | 1/1/2002
```

For my project I am looking to pull records of people who HAVE NOT voted in an election with the year of 2001.

Expected Output:

```
VOTER_ID | VOTER_NAME |
---------|------------|
10000002 | Jane Doe   |
```

I can get as far as selecting the instances in 2001 with `WHERE YEAR(ELECTION_DATE) <> 2017`, however that would still result in John Doe being included in the output.

Comment: On a side note: It is a bit rare to see the voter name in this table. It should rather be in the voter table the voter_id links to - unless you want to record the name history, e.g. that someone changed their name because of marriage and voted hence with another name in earlier years than they did later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by voter, keep voters that have no entry for year 2001.

```
select voter_id, voter_name
from mytable
group by voter_id, voter_name
having sum(year(election_date) = 2001) = 0
order by voter_id, voter_name;
```

This makes use of true=1, false=0 in MySQL. In standard SQL you'd use:

```
having sum(case when extract(year from election_date) = 2001 then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

which also works in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NOT IN from a SELECT that finds all id that voted 2001.

you should not save date or datetime in a varchar it should always be stpored in a DATe DATETIME. and on ly teh puitput should be formatet with DATE_FORMAR.

Strind to date is always slow and can't use INDEXES

> ```
> CREATE TABLE voters (
>   `Voter_ID` INTEGER,
>   `VOTER_NAME` VARCHAR(8),
>   `ELECTION_DATE` VARCHAR(10)
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO voters
>   (`Voter_ID`, `VOTER_NAME`, `ELECTION_DATE`)
> VALUES
>   ('10000001', 'John Doe', '1/1/2000'),
>   ('10000001', 'John Doe', '1/1/2001'),
>   ('10000001', 'John Doe', '1/1/2002'),
>   ('10000002', 'Jane Doe', '1/1/2000'),
>   ('10000002', 'Jane Doe', '1/1/2002');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT DISTINCT
>     `Voter_ID`, `VOTER_NAME`
> FROM
>     voters
> WHERE
>     `Voter_ID` NOT IN (SELECT 
>             `Voter_ID`
>         FROM
>             voters
>         WHERE
>             YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`ELECTION_DATE`, '%d/%m/%Y')) = 2001)
> ```
>
> ```
> Voter_ID | VOTER_NAME
> -------: | :---------
> 10000002 | Jane Doe
> ```

> ```
> SELECT `Voter_ID` FROM voters WHERE YEAR(STR_TO_DATE(`ELECTION_DATE`,'%d/%m/%Y')) = 2001
> ```
>
> ```
> | Voter_ID |
> | -------: |
> | 10000001 |
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=147cb8c2e72de037aece714e13d85de9)*

Comment: What makes you assume the election date is stored as a string in the database? Nobody in their right mind would do so. If we want to store dates, we use the `DATE` data type of course.

Comment: check the linked example, your data string has not the right fiormat for mysql it throws an error, so if your sample  data, arent't in the correct dat format, i must assume that you saved it soe. but try the exampe and change thet data type. it will fail

Comment: I see your example. And I wonder, why you make the date a string. The OP said that `YEAR(ELECTION_DATE)` worked so far as limiting rows, but didn't help ruling out 'John Doe'. Hence, `election_date` seems to be a date, as it should be.

Comment: i provided an example,and if give a valid answer, i can't enter the data in that example with  that format. So when mysqlm doesn't convert the date in DATE or DATETIME ad you will see it really doesn't.

Comment: I don't know what you are talking about really. Do you mean `1/1/2000` etc. in the request? This is just the display setting for dates in OP's database or software. It would probably show `01.01.2000` on my computer, because my settings are German. The election date is stored as `DATE` in the database, making it possible that the OP sees `1/1/2000` while I see `01.01.2000`. Dates should be stored as dates and entered as dates (e.g. `DATE '2020-01-01'`). Or are you referring to something else?

Comment: Look at the e-x-a-m-p-l-e change the colum to date or datetime. please

Comment: Haha, sorry, somehow we are not talking the same language. I read the request, I read your answer, I looked at your dbfiddle. What else do you want me to look at? Here is a fiddle with a DATE column: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=29b46fc2fbdcf93541cbcef1fcc3fb7c